# n-fold convolution of a probability function

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods, convolution, signal-processing

I have few questions about convolutions.

1. I have a sample data sheet in the form of $x$ vs $f(x)$. [discrete points]

Now I want to do $3-$fold convolution of $f(x)$ and plot the 3-fold convoluted functions w.r.t $x$. How to do it?

2. suppose length of $f(x)$ is $10$. So, length of $x$ is also $10$. After $2-$fold convolution (i.e $f_2(x)=f(x)* f(x)$), length of $f_2(x)$ will be $19$, but original length of $x$ is still $10$. Then how to plot $f_2(x)$ w.r.t $x$?

Kindly give some suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: What do you mean by "length of $f(x)$ is $10$"?

Comment: Length of f(x) means there are 10 elements in the array of f(x).

Comment: Either extend x or truncate the output.